# A form that is saved real-time. Practical?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to build a very user-friendly user interface for my site. The standard right now is to use client side as well as server side validation for forms. Right? I was wondering if I could just forgo client side validation, and rely simply on server side. The validation would be triggered on blur, and will use ajax.
To go one step ahead, I was also planning to save a particular field in the database if it has been validated as correct. Something like a real-time form update.

You see, I am totally new to programming. So I dont know if this approach can work practically. I mean, will there be speed or connection problems? Will it take toll on the server in case of high traffic? Will the site slow down on HTTPS?
Are there any site out there which have implemented this?

Also, the way I see it, I would need a separate PHP script for every field! Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Some of the things you say don't really make sense. If you are totally new, you should try to understand first how to do simple websites and forms, and get familiar with PHP, Ajax, etc.

Comment: @Laurent true, but we must follow our passions. it's hard to learn guitar if you want to sound like Led Zeppelin but are practicing on an acoustic that makes you sound like Garth Brooks. Very demotivating!

Comment: @daniel: wrong. Basics are basic. Whether you want to play led zepelin, slipknot or eric clapton, basics are same. It doesn't matter the guitar is electric, acoustic, hollow, bass.... All plays the same notes. If you know how to play, you can play slipknot in acoustic. Similiarly, OP needs to get the basics 1st. Laurent is right.

Comment: @itachi if you were right, I would be able to play the guitar but not program. Instead it's the other way around.

Comment: Offtopic but let me say, your approach is wrong in this case. I play hard rock, metal in both acoustic and electric. What depends is the scale. If you think rock, metal is only about distortion, amplifier then it won't help you.  Don't get infatuated with the sound. If you only want that "sound" and found demotivating in other guitars, you won't be able to play. Give more importance on playing notes accurate, speed (on whatever guitar). These are the basics. And if you can play it in acoustic, you'l be master in electric cz acoustic is harder to play.

Comment: I am totally new to programming: true. I didnt know what JS was 15 days ago, or php 25 days ago, or css 30 days ago.
But I can handle ajax, php, html, css, Jquery et al. I have successfully implemented a user management system, an ajax save/load/submit form, along with generation of pdf based on the data. 

And I do actually know how to implement the logic I mentioned; I just want to know if I will run into trouble later on.

Comment: @user1213097 - it's more work, but if it's what you desire, do it.

Comment: @itachi you're reading too much into the metaphor. I'm saying that if something sparked his interest in doing it this way, even if it would be out of reach to a beginner, his passion is more likely to carry him through it and to the lessons he needs than forcing him to take a sharp detour through basics that seem unnecessary to him now. if you want to continue this debate we should find a more appropriate venue and you should supply an answer below.

Comment: @op: its very easy to create a site. But it is much harder to make it secure. After learning php for 4 or 5 days, anyone can make website. But to make it less vulnerable, you need to apply filtration, sanitization. To know the flaws, you need to know how things works. This is where basic comes in. You want to go advance stages quickly? Its absolutely without any harm but the problem here is, most people ignore the basics on this process. It would be like cramming mathematics. My advice is, learn as much as you can. But don't forget the basics.

Comment: Ive been trying to make it secure as well. Preventing injections, sanitizing etc ... - done that. I am also taking steps to prevent session hijacking.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is very doable. In fact, this is the out-of-the-box functionality you would get if you were using JSF with a rich component framework like ICEfaces or PrimeFaces.

Like all web technology, being able to do it with one language means you can do it with others. I have written forms like you describe in PHP manually. It's a substantial amount of work, and when you're first getting started it will definitely be easiest with one script per field backing the form. As you get better, you will discover how you can include the field name in the request and back it down to one script for Ajax interactions per form. You can of course reduce the burden even further.

PHP frameworks may be able to make this process less onerous, but I haven't used them and would recommend you avoid them initially until you get your bearings. The magic that a system like Cake or Rails provides is very helpful but you have to understand the tradeoffs and the underlying technology or it will be very hard to build robust systems atop their abstractions.

Calculating the server toll is not intuitive. On the one hand, handling large submissions is more work than handling smaller ones. It may be that you are replacing one big request with several tiny ones for a net gain. It's going to depend on the kind of work you have to do with each form field. For example, auto completion is much more expensive than checking for a username already being taken, which is more expensive than (say) verifying that some string is actually a number or some other obvious validation.

Since you don't want to repeat yourself it's very tempting to put all your validation on one side or the other, but there are tradeoffs either way, and it is true that server-side validation is going to be slower than client-side. But the speed of client-side validation is no substitute for the fact that it will introduce security problems if you count on it. So my general approach is to do validation on the server-side, and if I have time, I will add it to the client side as well so as to improve responsiveness. (In point of fact, I actually start with validation in the database as much as possible, then in the server-side code, then client-side, because this way even if my app blows up I don't have invalid data sticking around to worry about).

It used to be that you could expect your site to run about 1/3 as fast under SSL. I don't have up-to-date numbers but it will always be more expensive than unencrypted. It's just plain more work. SSL setup is also not a great deal of fun. Most sites I've worked on either put the whole thing under SSL, or broke the site into some kind of shopping cart which was encrypted and left the rest alone. I would not spend undue energy trying to optimize this. If you need encryption, use it and get on with your day.

At your stage of the game I would not lose too much sleep over performance. Since you're totally new, focus on the learning process, try to implement the features that you think will be gratifying and aim for improvement. It's easy to obsess about performance, but you're not going to have the kind of traffic that will squash you for a long time, unless half the planet is going to want to buy your product and your site is extremely heavy and your host extremely weak. When it comes, you should profile your code and find where you are doing too much work and fix that, and you will get much further than if you try and design up front a performant system. You just don't have enough data yet to do that. And most servers these days are well beyond equipped to handle fairly heavy load—you're probably not going to have hundreds of visitors per second sustained in the near future, and it will take a lot more than that to bring down a $20 VPS running a fairly simple PHP site. Consider that one visitor a second works out to about 80,000 hits a day, you'd need 8 million hits a day to reach 100/second. You're not going to need a whole second to render a page unless you've done something stupid. Which we all do, a few times, when we're learning. :)

Good luck on your journey!

Comment: I dont have SSL yet - its just a possibility.
And yes, I wont really be getting huge traffic. The actual point was that I expect 70% of my yearly traffic in two specific months because of the nature of my trade. But yes, my site isnt going to explode or anything. 
I can reduce it down to one script - as you said using 'sending the field name' in request. Sounds good. But I think I'll go for saving the form using ajax every 20 - 30 seconds. And later on get back to real-time update.

Comment: You will probably find that to be more trouble than real-time, but it's a fair plan. Give it a shot and bring your problems back here to S.O.

Comment: yes, it sound like more trouble.
I can use HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and explode to get field names. And then use functions to update my db field by field. This way my php script will be able to handle individual as well as several data record updates without losing out on time. Notice any flaw here?